# Adding a distribution list from a shared mailbox to another distribution list in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I'm trying to add a distribution group contained in a shared mailbox to another distribution list. However when I click "add members" none of the distribution lists in the shared mailbox appear under contacts, only the distribution lists stored under my personal mailbox appear.

Could anyone help me out here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: What have you tried so far?